# Is there any way to keyframe values within a SimpleDeform modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I am incredibly new to 3d animation and modeling after perfecting 2D animation via motion graphics for the past few years. I've found it best for myself to just jump into programs and play around to learn various functions.

I've started running through some of the modifiers; however, it would seem as though there is no way to add a keyframe when changing the value of a property within a simpledeform.

For example: I'd like the angle of a Twist modifier to be 208 degrees at frame 24, and to be 0 at frame 0.

Afterward I would like to be able to smooth out the f-curve between the two keyframes to create an interesting look where my primitive untwists.

Is this simply not a functionality of this program? If so, in what programs would I be able to do this?

Thank you in advance. I apologize if this is extremely basic I truly just don't have any idea what is going on after doing quite a few searches for this myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can like most other fields in blender. You just need to remember the shortcut <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering over the field or simply right-click (on the field) > Add keyframe. The field's color is yellow when a keyframe is set to the current frame, and green when at least one keyframe is set to another frame. Remember to change the current frame in the timeline when you change keyframes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @wells_fuego Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :). So it's easier for others to find.